# How to make an api call once in a multiple component

Tags: vue.js

I am studying Vue.js (3).

I have a component which is used a lot of time (in a loop). The render is something like that :

[image]

This component makes a get (Axios) when it is created. So if I have 10 loops, I have 10 gets which return the same thing.

I try to make only 1 call (at the first component) and not the other calls, without the use of vuex. Is it possible in Vue.js and how to do that ? (I tried "mounted" instead of "created", without success).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the request in the parent component in which the loop is rendered. After that pass the response data as a prop to each item.